# 'Ambiguous column name '

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

When i execute the below query:

```
select ProjectID, UserID, * 
from UserDetails 
where ProjectId='123456' 
order by UserID
```

I get 'Ambiguous column name UserID' as error

However, when i write the same query as:

```
select ProjectID, UserID, * 
from UserDetails UD 
where ProjectId='123456' 
order by UD.UserID
```

it doesn't throw any error.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: `*` expands to all columns, which includes another UserID instance.

Comment: You are selecting columns twice...Explicitly via UserID, Implicitly via *

Comment: @bub i get your point. But the same happens in second query also. Right?

Comment: @Darshan yes it does

Comment: You are selecting from a single table, you can either select all columns or specify required columns. No need to provide column names as well as *

Comment: @bub so why the second query doesn't throw any error?

Comment: The 2nd query doesn't throw an error because you have already aliased one set of fields, so there is no overlap with the other set.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, you could select it as accepted with the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have selected the column twice. Using the wildcard `*` selects all columns. The 2nd query doesn't throw an error as you noticed because you have already aliased one set of fields, so there is no overlap with the other set.

Answer (score 0):

For quick clarification, the order by UD.UserId creates the Alias in the select. That's why the second query doesn't show an error. Because the table was specified.

Comment: Not quite. The alias is the UD here, `from UserDetails UD`